# What is the nominal operating frequency of a solid state relay dc input to dc output and the current that is pumping through it is 6 amps?

Tags: solid-state-relay

[image]

For my project I am using an Hbridge circuit for my load is an electromagnet. So the frequency cycle is around 500 Hz to 1 kHz . Is it safer to use solid state relays for this operating frequency?

Datasheet of SSR https://www.futurlec.com/Datasheet/Relays/HFS33.pdf

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: If you can't add a link to the datasheet, we'll have to close this question as unclear :(

Comment: https://www.futurlec.com/Datasheet/Relays/HFS33.pdf

Comment: @MarcusMüller Your comment sounds like it's OK to post a datasheet here and have it read to oneself aloud by someone. I don't feel this kind of questions would be appropriate.

Comment: The title isn't even comprehensible English.  No point reading further.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev while I in principle agree, many datasheets are so hard to interpret that getting the info needed from them is engineering by itself. This one, not so much.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Point taken, I admit I didn't bother to check out this datasheet, and I agree that you were right to ask for one before voting to close.

Answer (score 6):

The data sheet says max on and off times are \$500\mu S\$.

At 1kHz, that means the device could spend all its time switching.

It is not suitable for switching at that speed.

Answer (score 3):

Your device is a DC output solid state relay and you will need 4 of them to make a H bridge. Given that you need 4 of them and given the switching restriction mentioned by Neil it will be a bad choice for what you want. I really would recommend making a proper H bridge that is capable of running at the switching speed you want most efficiently.

You can get MOSFET driver chips from various sources that avoid "shoot-through" (it could be a serious problem if you didn't design the H bridge correctly) and you should be able to use 4 N channel MOSFETs to achieve what you want. Here's the general idea for a half bridge: -

[image]

And the LT1162 can be used to create a full H bridge driver. It all depends on what your input DC voltage is of course; some designs will be more appropriate than others.